# Regex replace \" with "

Tags: regex, string

I am trying to replace \" sequence with ".

```
line = "\\\"time\\\":1505050505,\\\"event\\\":check";
line = line.replaceAll("\\\"", "\"");
```

This does not give me desired output of `""time":15050505,"event":check"`

Instead I get: `\"time\":1505050505,\"event\":check`

Why is this?

Comment: Use `line = line.replace("\\\"", "\"");`

Comment: AGH! That was it. Thanks. :(